# Slow performance in Angular 6/Ionic 4 PWA when using lots of content editable divs

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, ionic-framework

I am experiencing really slow performance, particularly on older machines when trying to move between content editable boxes.

I think this may be due to the amount of nodes being wrote to the DOM. It is important for me to display all of these nodes because it is for comparative analysis.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is below:-

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  this.testArray.push(i);
}

<ng-container *ngFor="let row of testArray">
    <div contentEditable="true">{{row}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

I'm using chromes performance cpu throttling on x6 slowdown to emulate this.

In my full example I also have functions bound to these elements but it's a lot of code to include here.

I have thought about only loading into view what is needed but I'm unsure how to do this and it needs to be scrollable on both the x and y axis.

Comment: Can you share more of context as to how you need this to work - do you expect data model to update after "edit" is done by a user?

Answer (score 1):

I think that one way to optimize the performance of the application is to execute those loops outside NgZone, and send the update until the end of the loop so that actions are not being triggered at each change, if not trigger a single action at the end of the loop.
[Here you can find more information](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

Answer (score 0):

Angular actually has a feature, called virtual scrolling. It has some limitations but may be what you need. For more info read here https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling

Also consider using pagination to decrease divs on page